# How do i take a screenshot of an autocomplete field?

Tags: screenshot

Exactly the question in the title;

I would like to take a screenshot of this:

[image]

Or at least this kind of object. It doesn't seem possible in any other program either as far as i'm aware, the drop down menu goes away when i try to screenshot. I can't do it with either just pressing the screenshot key, or using the image magick `import` command bound to a keyboard shortcut. I just end up with this:

[image]

Is there any way to do this?

Will

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running Windows, SnagIt should be able to handle this just fine: http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html

Comment: Im on unix actually...

I currently get all my screenshots either using import, or the regular  print screen, was hoping there wasa way to get what i want using these...